# Keep the exact status of previous page, including toggled out element by javascript when run window.history.back() in the following page

Tags: javascript, html

I have developed a web app in HTML5.
I have two pages, 1.html, and a back button in 2.html, which run window.history.back() function to back to previous url(in my case would open the url corresponding to 1.html).
I have created some javascript in 1.html to toggle some hidden element to style.display = "block".
But after the user toggled the hidden element to a showing one and enter into the next page(2.html), the user complains that the showing element in previous page should show when he click  back button.

How could I add some script after window.history.back() method, so when use run it in the following page, the toggled out element in previous page by the user could be shown?

1.html:

```
<button class="button" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">toggle out</button>
<div id="myDIV" style="display:none;">previously Hidden words</div>
 function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";

    }
}
```

2.html:

```
     <button class="button"  onclick="goBack()">Back</button>
    function goBack() {
window.history.back();

    }
```

when user clicked "toggle out" button in page1 to make "myDIV" section shown, and then go into page2. The user want to see the toggled out myDIV section after clicking back button in page2.
He believes that back button should show the exact status of page 1 when he jumps into page2

Comment: Store the settings in the local / session storage and load them on page load.

Comment: which value should I save in the session? Seems like only the value could be save using sessionStorage.setItem, but I want to save the display status

Comment: You should store all the changeable values, in your example store the value of `x.style.display`.

Comment: why that element in previous page would not being there after using window.history.back();?

Comment: Because the page is completely reloaded and initialized. All elements are in the initial state.